# How to handle CRLF line endings in grep?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Suppose I have an arbitrary text input that contains CRLF line endings:

```
$ curl -sI http://unix.stackexchange.com | head -4
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
Content-Length: 80551
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

$ curl -sI http://unix.stackexchange.com | head -4 | hexdump -C
00000000  48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31  20 32 30 30 20 4f 4b 0d  |HTTP/1.1 200 OK.|
00000010  0a 43 61 63 68 65 2d 43  6f 6e 74 72 6f 6c 3a 20  |.Cache-Control: |
00000020  70 75 62 6c 69 63 2c 20  6d 61 78 2d 61 67 65 3d  |public, max-age=|
00000030  36 30 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74  65 6e 74 2d 4c 65 6e 67  |60..Content-Leng|
00000040  74 68 3a 20 38 30 39 30  32 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65  |th: 80902..Conte|
00000050  6e 74 2d 54 79 70 65 3a  20 74 65 78 74 2f 68 74  |nt-Type: text/ht|
00000060  6d 6c 3b 20 63 68 61 72  73 65 74 3d 75 74 66 2d  |ml; charset=utf-|
00000070  38 0d 0a                                          |8..|
00000073
```

GNU `grep` 2.26 does not handle such input very well with respect to line endings:

```
$ curl -sI http://unix.stackexchange.com | head -4 | grep '200 OK$'
$ curl -sI http://unix.stackexchange.com | head -4 | grep '200 OK.$'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

This is a little annoying. I can of course resolve this by including `dos2unix` into the pipeline:

```
$ curl -sI http://unix.stackexchange.com | head -4 | dos2unix | grep '200 OK$'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

but this feels a little hamfisted (and not very portable).

<s>The weird thing in general is that the `grep(2)` man page claims that the tool will strip any CRs in the input, unless the input has been detected as binary:</s>

```
-U, --binary
       Treat the file(s) as binary.  By default, under MS-DOS and MS-Windows,
       grep guesses whether a file is text or binary  as  described  for  the
       --binary-files  option.   If  grep decides the file is a text file, it
       strips the CR characters from the  original  file  contents  (to  make
       regular  expressions  with  ^  and  $  work correctly).  Specifying -U
       overrules this guesswork, causing all files to be read and  passed  to
       the matching mechanism verbatim; if the file is a text file with CR/LF
       pairs  at  the  end  of  each  line,  this  will  cause  some  regular
       expressions  to  fail.   This  option has no effect on platforms other
       than MS-DOS and MS-Windows.
```

**EDIT:** As stated in the manpage, this behaviour is MS-DOS and MS-Windows specific.

Is it possible to make `grep` transparently handle CRLF (and CR) line endings without preprocessing the input? If not, is this something that should be patched, or is there a well-founded rationale?

Comment: Modifying a pipeline by adding a filter partway through should not feel hamfisted.  It's a Unix norm.  `dos2unix` may not be portable, but `tr` and `sed` are and can do the same filtering.  It's a `perl` one-liner, too.

Comment: Sure, but it still adds complexity to the command and this strikes me as a common enough problem to warrant direct support within `grep`.

Comment: A sed equivalent of `dos2unix` is `sed 's/\r$//'`

Comment: … which is equivalent to using the pattern `something\r\?$` instead of `something$` directly within grep. Still, it is an annoyance and a level of detail I would expect grep to abstract away (if I ask nicely enough through some flag). Suppose you are grepping through a file that uses only `\r` to end lines (the way old macs did). Then it becomes more than an annoyance, since `grep` will not recognize these as line endings and buffer the entire file as a single line. Of course, `sed 's/\r/\n/g'` will fix this, but how would anyone think having to do this is a good idea baffles me.

Comment: plus these filter solutions aren't suitable when I want to grep in multiple files in one go, like `grep "pattern$" *.txt`

Answer (score 3):

based on this page. try these solutions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73833/how-do-you-search-for-files-containing-dos-line-endings-crlf-with-grep-on-linu

```
curl -sI http://unix.stackexchange.com | head -4  | grep "200 OK$(printf '\r')" 

grep -IUlr $'\r'
```

Comment: I can of course use `$(printf '\r')` – or `$'\r'` in bash – to insert a literal CR into the pattern. What I'm asking, however, is if there is a way for me to not have to do that. I'd like to match line endings transparently (i.e. regardless of whether they consist of a CR, LF, or CRLF).

Comment: As I indicated in the comment section of the original question, this goes deeper than playing with the pattern, since grep will only buffer lines terminated by `\n`, whereas `\r` does not terminate a line from the buffering standpoint.